# django SSL apache configuration

Tags: django, apache, ssl

I have a django application and I would like to apply SSL to the admin pages. Since the admin page are the only pages needing SSL I want to do this using the apache configuration files and not using SSLMiddleware. My (partial) apache configuration files look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    .
    .
    DocumentRoot /home/www/sites_django/wmssite
    .
    <Directory "/home/www/sites_django/wmssite">
        .
    </Directory>

    <Location "/admin">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.whitemoorstudio.pvm/admin [L,R=301]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/etc/apache22/www_whitemoorstudio_pvm.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/etc/apache22/www_whitemoorstudio_pvm.key"
    .
    .
</VirtualHost>
```

The TLD .pvm is a local TLD I just use for testing on my internal network.

I have set up a self-sgned certificate and it works, well.... sort of. The strange thing is that for some reason when rewriting to https it cannot find the media files in the /media directory, no images, no css, no js. The apache error log tells me it is looking in the directory /usr/local/www/apache22/data/media:

```
[Sat Nov 06 20:45:18 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.134] File does not exist: /usr/local/www/apache22/data/media, referer: https://www.whitemoorstudio.pvm/admin/
```

When I don't rewrite to https the admin media directory /usr/local/www/apache22/media. This directory media is a logical link:

```
media -> /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media
```

I have no idea why without SSL it is looking in:

```
/usr/local/www/apache22/media
```

and with SSL in:

```
/usr/local/www/apache22/data/media
```

This last directory doesn't exist!!!

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem already solved. When adding the stuff in the VirtualHost *:443 container

I had forgotten to specify the DocumentRoot directive so it was as specified in the main httpd.conf.

It went well in the VirtualHost *:80 container because in that section I had specified DocumentRoot.

In httpd.conf it is specified as:
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache22/data"

Comment: Thanks for asking and solving this. I will be doing the same thing in a few days and this will give me a great starting place.

Comment: You're welcome. I also changed the rewrite rule into: RewriteRule ^/admin(.*) https://www.whitemoorstudio.pvm/admin [L,R=301]. Also note that the file locations are for my FreeBSD server.